# WP echo get_user_meta single value prints 'array'

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display the `line_managers`'s `nickname` of a given `user_id` from my WP usermeta table.

The table looks like this:

`user_id` `2` has the `line_manager` value  `1`

[image]

'user_id' `1` has the `nickname` value `MyNicknameString`

[image]

**Desired Result**

```
User ID: 2
Line Manager ID: 1
Line Manager Nickname: MyNicknameString
```

**PHP**

```
User ID: 
<?php echo bp_displayed_user_id(); ?>
<br>

Line Manager ID: 
<?php
$line_manager = get_user_meta( bp_displayed_user_id() , 'line_manager' , true );
echo $line_manager;
?>
<br>

Line Manager Nickname: 
<?php
$line_manager = get_user_meta( bp_displayed_user_id() , 'line_manager' , true );
$line_manager_nickname = get_user_meta( $line_manager , 'nickname' , true );
echo $line_manager_nickname;
?>
```

**Current Result**

```
User ID: 2
Line Manager ID: Array
Line Manager Nickname:
```

How do I correctly reference these key values?

---

EDIT: `var_dump($line_manager)` returns array data from the `users` table rather than the expected `usermeta` table. I would have expected it to print the `usermeta`.

---

EDIT 2: The following SQL works as I would expect the WP function to.

```
global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
$displayed_user = bp_displayed_user_id();
$line_manager_ID =  $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$table_prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$displayed_user." AND meta_key = 'line_manager' ");
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$table_prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$line_manager_ID." AND meta_key = 'nickname' ");
```

Comment: Make sure the `line_manager` value in your database doesn't have any leading / trailing whitespace

Comment: @Phil Can confirm no whitespace

Comment: I'd suggest you `var_dump` `$line_manager_nickname` to see what is inside the array that the get meta function is returning.

Comment: @JoshBonnick `var_dump($line_manager_nickname)` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: What about `var_dump($line_manager)`? What's in that array that it's returning? Also, what version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: @JoshBonnick Latest version of WP. `var_dump($line_manager)` returns `array(10) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_login"]=> string(3) "MyNicknameString" ["user_nicename"]=> string(3) "MyNicknameString" ["user_email"]=> string(17) "EMAILADDRESS" ["user_url"]=> string(25) "SITEURL" ["user_registered"]=> string(19) "2020-10-14 19:43:01" ["user_activation_key"]=> string(0) "" ["user_status"]=> string(1) "0" ["display_name"]=> string(3) "MyNicknameString" ["pod_item_id"]=> string(1) "1"}`

Comment: Don't see any `line_manager` in there. Are you sure you're looking at the right database in PHPMyAdmin? Also, why would `ID` be `1` when the user ID you're requesting is `2`? There's just not enough debugging information here to help

Comment: @Phil (Edited comment.) It looks like this var dump is coming from `users` rather than `usermeta` - I don't understand that

Comment: But presumably, this array is all the user meta data for the requested ID (`2`). You're getting this array either because you're not actually passing in a `$key` (likely) or for some reason, Wordpress is returning an array because the `line_manager` key doesn't exist. This seems unlikely as it's not indicated in the docs

Comment: @Phil As per screenshot, I can see line_manager in the usermeta - so surely it exists? I checked whitespace by looking at the inspector when viewing phpMyAdmin, which is `<span>line_manager</span>` - so no whitespace. I am using the Pods plugin to extend the usermeta, but I wouldn't have thought this is related given I can see it on the database.

Comment: Seems impossible for `var_dump($line_manager)` to return that array, when I tested dumping `get_user_meta()` on my environment with an invalid `key`, just returns and empty array, and with `single` set to true returns `bool(false)`. Have you dumped `get_user_meta(bp_displayed_user_id())` to see full result?

Comment: @Phil The following works: `<?php 
global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
$displayed_user = bp_displayed_user_id();
$line_manager_ID =  $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$table_prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$displayed_user." AND meta_key = 'line_manager' ");
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$table_prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$line_manager_ID." AND meta_key = 'nickname' "); 
?>` FOR EASY READING: https://pastebin.pl/view/ffc40822

Comment: @joshmoto see last comment. this works: https://pastebin.pl/view/ffc40822

Comment: @redditor can you pastbin the result of this var_dump(get_user_meta(bp_displayed_user_id()))

Comment: just curious does it work if your hardcode the id like `$line_manager = get_user_meta( 2 , 'line_manager', true );`?

Comment: @joshmoto https://pastebin.pl/view/a7f130f6

Comment: @mikerojas can confirm `$line_manager = get_user_meta( 2 , 'line_manager', true );` does not work

Comment: The reason why you get an array is simply because the value associated with  `line_manager` key is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, see comments explaining a bit better what is happing here...

[@redditor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045794/redditor) in your last [paste bin](https://pastebin.pl/view/d83934c6) comment you are getting the `$line_manager_id` too early, you need to make sure `$user_meta['line_manager'][0]` is set before attempting to get this id or you will get an error or warning... see my updated answer below with comments

```
<?php
    
// get current user id the wordpress way
// $user_id = get_current_user_id();

// get displayed user your way
$user_id = bp_displayed_user_id();

// get user meta data
$user_meta = get_user_meta($user_id);

// if we have user id
if($user_id) { ?>

    User ID: <?=$user_id?>
    <br/>

    <?php // if line manager array key and sub key 0 is set ?>    
    <?php if(isset($user_meta['line_manager'][0])) { ?>

        <?php // here it is safe to now get the line manager user meta ?> 
        <?php $lm_user_meta = get_user_meta($user_meta['line_manager'][0]); ?>

        Line Manager ID: <?=$user_meta['line_manager'][0]?>
        <br/>
        
        <?php // check line manager user meta array nickname key and sub key 0 is set ?> 
        <?php if(isset($lm_user_meta['nickname'][0])) { ?>
            
            Line Manager Nickname: <?=$lm_user_meta['nickname'][0]?>
            
        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This results as: `User ID: 2` - correct. `Line Manager ID: 1` - correct. `Line Manager Nickname: User2Nickname` - incorrect.

Comment: @joshmoto the line manager is a different user account so you'd need `$line_manager_user_meta = get_user_meta($user_meta['line_manager'][0]); echo $line_manager_user_meta['nickname'][0];`

Comment: Thanks both @Phil. I have accepted as correct. https://pastebin.pl/view/d83934c6

Comment: @Phil Is the current answer edit with the nested query more efficient than this method: https://pastebin.pl/view/d83934c6

Comment: @joshmoto so it is, UK also. https://0bin.net/paste/GPeY1eSq#AfeNo9a55tBiYWAUfbla5j5LGJBzE9YKxb8iTG0G2ls

Comment: @joshmoto ignore my poor choice of var names for line manager

Comment: @redditor in your last paste bin your are getting the `$line_manager_id` to early, you need to make sure `$user_meta['line_manager'][0]` is set before attempting to get this id, see my updated answer with comments